# pg_basebackup not showing 100% of backup on the status feedback

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

Whenever I do backup with pg_basebackup, sometimes I see the following

```
$ pg_basebackup -D /mnt/dbstorage/backup/`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S` -Ft -R -Xs -z -c fast -P -U replicator -h 10.200.160.24
Password: 
266898642/267239525 kB (99%), 1/1 tablespace
```

It only shows the 99% and exits normally. I am not sure why ? is it an expected behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing to worry about.

The database shrank a little bit between when the total size was calculated at the beginning, and when the backup finished.  Maybe some relation or index got dropped, maybe vacuum was able to truncate empty data off the end of a table.